# Closed immersion hitting all the $\mathbb{Q}$-points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, diophantine-geometry

Let $i:X\to Y$ be a closed immersion of smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Assume that $Y(\mathbb{Q})$ is infinite and $X(\mathbb{Q})\to Y(\mathbb{Q})$ is surjective. Also assume that $X$ is not ruled and that $Y$ is a complete intersection.

Then can we relate the geometric invariants (e.g. plurigenera, Hodge numbers) of $X$ to those of $Y$?

Comment: Don't you want to assume that $Y(Q)$ is Zariski dense? Otherwise just assuming it's infinite doesn't say much.

Comment: @YCor I feel that assuming density would be too much

Comment: Say, take $Y_0$ with a single rational point, $f_0:X_0\to Y_0$ a closed immersion with $X_0(Q)$ nonempty. Then for $X=X_0\times P^1$, $Y=Y_0\times P^1$, $f=f_0\times\mathrm{id}$ your assumptions are fulfilled. Hence infiniteness of $Y(Q)$ is not really more (after changing the variety) than assuming it's nonempty.

Comment: @YCor The assumption that $Y(\mathbb Q)$ is Zariski dense doesn't seem to lead to an interesting question either -- since $X$ is supposed to be a closed subvariety this would lead to $X=Y$.

Comment: @DanPetersen you're right: maybe rather $X(Q)$ Zariski-dense in $X$? Anyway I'm puzzled how these arithmetic assumptions pertain to the question (e.g., what are phenomena that could occur in a general setting $X\subset Y$ but seem to rule out the presence of too many rational points)?

Comment: **Question:** "Then can we relate the geometric invariants (e.g. plurigenera, Hodge numbers) of X to those of Y?"


**Answer:** This is too long for a comment hence I post it as an answer: Given any projective scheme $X:=Proj(\mathbb{Q}[x_0,..,x_n]/I) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{Q}}$, you may choose another ideal $J \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[x_0,..,x_n]$ with $J=(f_1,..,f_l)$ with $deg(f_i)=D$ and $X \cong Proj(\mathbb{Q}[x_i]/J)$. Then you define $F:=f_1^2+\cdots +f_l^2$ and $H_{X,f_i}:=Proj(\mathbb{Q}[x_i]/(F))$.

Comment: There is a closed immersion

$$X \subseteq H_{X,f_i} \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{Q}}$$

and an equality $X(\mathbb{Q})=H_{X,f_i}(\mathbb{Q})$. The construction of $H_{X,f_i}$ depends on the set of generators $f_i$ for $J$ and for this reason it follows $H_{X,f_i}$ is not unique. The Hodge numbers of $H_{X,f_i}$ are polynomials in $2D$ and $n$ and $X$ is arbitrary. There is no reason for the Hodge numbers of an arbitrary $X$  to be a polynomial in two integers $2D,n$.

Comment: You could choose $F':=f_1^{2^m}+\cdots f_l^{2^m}$ for any integer $m \geq 1$ and get a hypersurface $H'_{X,f_i}$ of higher degree $d$. Hence there are many hypersurfaces $H$ of varying degrees containing $X$ as a closed subscheme and with the same rational points $X(\mathbb{Q})=H(\mathbb{Q})$. These differing hypersurfaces $H$ will have Hodge numbers that are polynomials in their degrees $d$ and the integer $n$. There is no reason to be a relation between the Hodge numbers of $X$ for arbitrary $X$ and these different hypersurfaces.

Comment: The elementary construction of the hypersurface $H_X$ above is discussed in another thread: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382762/rational-points-on-hypersurfaces **Note:** This post was deleted by abx and Kohl, but I still believe the examples may be of general interest because of the fact they are "elementary" and because you easily get many counter-examples.